# Enable Tailwind CSS IntelliSense in vscode even the tailwind was uninstalled?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

I export all the styles into bit.dev. So, I remove all tailwind set up in the project. But, I have no autocompletes anymore from the extension? how to enable the tailwind autocomplete and suggestion from tailwind intellisense?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Vscode for your IDE, after installing Tailwind IntelliSense you can try to select Tailwind format for your language mode.

Comment: Please add context or screenshots of where to do this.